# No method named `generate_keypair` found for type `secp256k1::Secp256k1` in the current scope

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use the secp256k1 library in Rust. I have a simple test program that fails to compile because it cannot find [`generate_keypair`](https://www.wpsoftware.net/rustdoc/secp256k1/struct.Secp256k1.html#method.generate_keypair):

```
extern crate secp256k1;
extern crate rand;

use secp256k1::{Secp256k1, ContextFlag};
use rand::{thread_rng};

fn main() {
    let full = Secp256k1::with_caps(ContextFlag::Full);
    let (sk, pk) = full.generate_keypair(&mut thread_rng()).unwrap();
}
```

This fails to compile with the error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `generate_keypair` found for type `secp256k1::Secp256k1` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:9:25
  |
9 |     let (sk, pk) = full.generate_keypair(&mut thread_rng()).unwrap();
  |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

As far as I can tell, I'm using the library similarly to [how its used in the library's tests](https://github.com/apoelstra/rust-secp256k1/blob/master/src/lib.rs#L658).

I've rolled back rand to 0.3 and secp256k1 to 0.6 and now it works. I'miInterested in any thoughts as to why this is now broken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation for secp256k1 version 0.8.1](https://docs.rs/secp256k1/0.8.1/secp256k1/struct.Secp256k1.html) on docs.rs does not list any method `generate_keypair`.

If you [look at the source](https://github.com/apoelstra/rust-secp256k1/blob/37f310789458ad990c29701cad2023c72ceb9269/src/lib.rs#L541-L546), you see:

```
/// Generates a random keypair. Convenience function for `key::SecretKey::new`
/// and `key::PublicKey::from_secret_key`; call those functions directly for
/// batch key generation. Requires a signing-capable context.
#[inline]
#[cfg(any(test, feature = "rand"))]
pub fn generate_keypair<R: Rng>(&self, rng: &mut R)
```

The `generate_keypair` function is only available when you enable the optional `rand` dependency. This was introduced in [commit 29892960](https://github.com/apoelstra/rust-secp256k1/commit/298929600b622341a4987b5d8a54bd1fc388fd61). Unfortunately, the maintainer of this crate does not publish version tags to the git repository, so it's very difficult to tell what version this change happened in.

Comment: Wow, yep, updated my dependency file to:
`secp256k1 = {version = "0.8", features = ["rand"]}`
Thanks!